# Logstash mutate - add field with dot not working

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-2.0, dplyr

According to [elastic convention](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/event-conventions.html) we use dot for grouping.
However when I try to use a dot in add_field it stops working.

Working:

```
 mutate {
   add_field => {"foo" => "baz"}
 }
```

Not working:

```
 mutate {
   add_field => {"foo.bar" => "baz"}
 }
```

Not working:

```
 mutate {
   add_field => {"[foo][bar]" => "baz"}
 }
```

So how do I make it work with dot in field's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution.

This is working for me (for some unexplained reason):

```
 mutate {
   add_field => { "[][foo][bar]" => "baz" }
 }
```

Comment: I get "Invalid FieldReference" for that (logstash 7.16). The `"[foo][bar]"` version worked for me.